# Does tensorflow serving work with more than one input (or output)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-serving

According to: https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html#exporting-a-model-with-tensorflow-serving

> Any Keras model can be exported with TensorFlow-serving **(as long as it
>   only has one input and one output, which is a limitation of
>   TF-serving**)

Is this (still) true? I couldn't find other references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple input and output tensors and expose any combination of them in different signatures for the SavedModel, as long as you use the PREDICT interface of TF-serving. For examples, look at

https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/signature_defs

So while there may be a limitation in the Keras-exporter code as written (I haven't looked), there is no such limitation in SavedModel on TensorFlow Serving (the product I am working on regularly uses the feature)

Comment: However, is that possible to send multiple sets of inputs for prediction in single request. like batch? Say, I my usual input for prediction _(1,2,3)_ is `{"input": {src_ids: "[1,2,3]"}}`. Could I predict for both _1,2,3_ and _4,5,6_ in single request?